# Spring security login to web by token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, token

I would like to login user on web page but not using username and password but token.
So I have two tables

```
User:
id
username
password

Token:
id
user_id
token
```

So now if user open in browser page domain.com/token/{token}
then should find user_id by token and load for that user roles, prives, etc.

I was googling about that but only found solutions for JWT (Rest API).

thanks for advice

**UPDATE**
System will generate token for user and will add entry to `Token` table.

Ex: token is: token3333 for user with id 3 ;)

when user go to page domain.com/token/token3333 then automatically will be logged as user with id 3 without filling in username and password.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii here is a spring tutorial with token based auth.

Comment: @Reek i'm almost sure that tutorial isn't what I'm asking. There is 'X-Auth-Token' header send with token request so  that isn't what I need

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is easily extensible, but you will have to do it *by hand*.

I cannot really understand why your login system with one single token is better than the classical username+password login page, and IMHO you should think twice about the real reason for that.

A simple way would be to use a spring-mvc controller here that would process the url domain.com/token/{token}, find the user id in the database and directly build a fully authenticated authentication token. Then you just have to put in the SecurityContext obtained from the static methods of the SecurityContextHolder class.

If you prefer a nicer integration into Spring security without relying on spring-mvc, you should set up a setup a custom authentication processing filter that would use the token passed in the URL to build a valid custom Authentication. It should derive from AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. Then you should setup an `AuthenticationProvider` able to process that token and actually authenticate a user through the token, and inject it in the AuthenticationManage. There is much more boiling plate here, and for your current question I am really unsure whether it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for advice.